# numpy: get the squares coordinates in the mesh grid

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

In python, with numpy, I can generate a meshgrid

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 4)
    y = np.linspace(0, 10, 4)

    x,y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    print x,y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and I get:

```
[[  0.           3.33333333   6.66666667  10.        ]
 [  0.           3.33333333   6.66666667  10.        ]
 [  0.           3.33333333   6.66666667  10.        ]
 [  0.           3.33333333   6.66666667  10.        ]]
[[  0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
 [  3.33333333   3.33333333   3.33333333   3.33333333]
 [  6.66666667   6.66666667   6.66666667   6.66666667]
 [ 10.          10.          10.          10.        ]]
```

how I can get the elements (squares) of the meshgrid, with the vertex ?

example: the square upper-left have the vertexs

```
(0, 0)   (0,3.3)
(3.3,0)  (3.3, 3.3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that would be

```
np.dstack([x,y])[row:row+2, col:col+2, :]
```

Where `row, col` are the coordinates of the top-left corner for that square.  Won't work on the last row or column, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late by a way for that is as follows`np.hstack((x.reshape((x.size,1)),y.reshape((y.size,1))))`

Answer (score -1):

Check out the documentation for [numpy.ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).